# Passing a var from a forEach to another function

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

I'm trying to get a `var` from a `forEach` loop to a separate function. My example is pulled from a google charts function, which may be the cause of the confusion, however when I try to get `var` array from my `forEach` to the chart's `arrayToDataTable`, I get an `undefined` error. This is my code:

```js
function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
  //alert('Successfully processed!')
  console.log(data);
  var header = document.querySelector('.header');
  var bodytext = document.querySelector('.bodytext');
  let i = 1;
  data.forEach(function(data) {
    var array = data.Name
    console.log(array)
  })
};


google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart(nameArrays, array) {
  var daa = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'Percentage'],
    ["'" + array + "'", 1],
    ["'" + array + "'", 1]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'People Percentage',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(daa, options);
}
```

Comment: You are logging `array` into console but not actually pushing the data into an array

Comment: I don't get why another function is needed in forEach

Comment: In `showInfo`, what did you get from `console.log(data)`, and what is your expected outcome for `console.log(array)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the data into an array/varialbe outside of the loop from the loop, and make sure it is in the same scope as the one which declares the function you are going to use the value in.

This is the fix applied to your solution (Only including the essential areas of it)

```js
var data = [ // Array of records for data, this would be the initial object that you are looping through
    { Name: "Bruh1" },
    { Name: "Bruh2" },
    { Name: "Bruh3" },
];
var arr = []; // Declare the array to take the data outside the loop
data.forEach((data) => {
    arr.push(data.Name); // Push data.Name into an array outside the forEach loop
});

// Putting that data into your other function
console.log([
      ['Name', 'Percentage'],
      ["'" + arr[0] + "'", 1],
      ["'" + arr[1] + "'", 1],
      ["'" + arr[2] + "'", 1]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how you should aproach this problem. You should call `drawChart` inside the for-loop. I'm guessing `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` is not an asynchronous function call

```
function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
  //alert('Successfully processed!')
  console.log(data);
  var header = document.querySelector('.header');
  var bodytext = document.querySelector('.bodytext');
  let i = 1;
  data.forEach(function(data) {
    drawChart(nameArray, data.Name)
  })
};


google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

let daa;
function drawChart(nameArrays, name) {
  daa = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'Percentage']
  ].push(["'" + name + "'", 1]));

  var options = {
    title: 'People Percentage',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(daa, options);
}
```